# pulling data from a windows DOS prompt

Tags: php, string, parsing

**Update: FIGURED IT OUT**

Answer:
I figured it out.

After every character there was a hidden \0.

The fix is simply:

```
trim(str_replace("\0", '', $string))
```

ASCII output:

```
|0()|84(T)|0()|104(h)|0()|101(e)|0()|32( )|0()|110(n)|0()|117(u)|0()|109(m)|0()|98(b)|0()|101(e)|0()|114(r)|0()|32( )|0()|111(o)|0()|102(f)|0()|32( )|0()|112(p)|0()|101(e)|0()|110(n)|0()|100(d)|0()|105(i)|0()|110(n)|0()|103(g)|0()|32( )|0()|100(d)|0()|101(e)|0()|118(v)|0()|105(i)|0()|99(c)|0()|101(e)|0()|40(()|0()|115(s)|0()|41())|0()|32( )|0()|105(i)|0()|115(s)|0()|32( )|0()|48(0)|0()|46(.)|0()|13(
)|0()|
```

**Question:**

Here's a good example of a string I'm testing with:

$string = "The number of pending device(s) is 1.";

string(73) "The number of pending device(s) is 1."

The code I'm attempting to run is:

```
$string = "the number of pending device(s) is 1.";
if(strstr($string, "pending"))
{
    echo "Found";
}
```

Another one I've been testing is:

```
$text = "The number of pending device(s) is 1.";
        $re1='.*?'; # Non-greedy match on filler
        $re2='(?:[a-z][a-z]+)'; # Uninteresting: word
        $re3='.*?'; # Non-greedy match on filler
        $re4='(?:[a-z][a-z]+)'; # Uninteresting: word
        $re5='.*?'; # Non-greedy match on filler
        $re6='(?:[a-z][a-z]+)'; # Uninteresting: word
        $re7='.*?'; # Non-greedy match on filler
        $re8='((?:[a-z][a-z]+))';   # Word 1
        $re9='.*?'; # Non-greedy match on filler
        $re10='(\\d+)'; # Integer Number 1

        if ($c=preg_match_all ("/".$re1.$re2.$re3.$re4.$re5.$re6.$re7.$re8.$re9.$re10."/is", $text, $matches))
        {
            $word1=$matches[1][0];
            $int1=$matches[2][0];
            print "($word1) ($int1) \n";
        }
```

Now this works great if it were just a string.  I'm pulling data from a windows DOS prompt and I can echo the data out just fine, but unfortunately when I try to run the data through preg_match_all or strpos or strstr it always returns false.  Could this be an encoding issue?  All of the data echos out into the browser just fine.

Please help!

Comment: Have you tried explicitly converting it to a str? I significantly doubt it is encoding as I have run some seriously non-UTF8 strings through preg_match

Comment: Additionally, I am going to assume based on your regex knowledge that your strstr() call missing quotes is a typo

Comment: If the word is uninteresting, why do you look for it? Why do you even care it's two letters large? Why do you even count the words?

Comment: Yes the strstr " " was a typo, sorry.

As far as this goes, let me tell you what I've tested so far:

strstr($string, "pending"), strpos(), preg_match_all, stristr(), everything.  It literally is not being read. 

I've tried running it as strval($string), (string)$string, EVERYTHING.  I'm literally stumped right now.

Comment: The Windows command prompt isn't DOS, btw.  DOS is the name of an operating system, not its command interpreter.

Comment: I still prefer to call it the DOS prompt ;) maybe I'm old school.

Answer (score 0):

As demonstrated by your example, both `strstr()` and `preg_match_all()` work fine. As such, there is nothing further we can do but speculate.

Since it's a problem with the shell output you're reading and the key is the difference between that string and your test one, you need to edit this question or ask a new one, supplying your code "pulling data from a windows DOS prompt".

Also, "echoing out into the browser" is not a good way to inspect strings. Try reading the individual bytes. (I usually use a for loop, a hex editor or a packet capture utility.)

Comment: It's really strange though because I can run strstr($string, "p") and pull out data before this string, but just not this string.

Comment: Whitespace? It's pretty meaningless to speculate further -- just give us a code demonstrating the problem.